# Is there a way or app that allow me to configure my mobile hotspot as a real router?

Tags: wi-fi, internet, router

I live in Cuba , and the easiest and cheapest way to have internet in home is sharing it from a mobile, now I'm trying to configure a Google home mini, but it doesn't work because AP isolation, so I need to figure out a way that allow me to configure the hotspot as a real router to disable AP isolation and modify other parameters. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not buy a router which has a SIM card slot? It is a one-time investment and it would save you from the hassle of figuring out if hotspot on Android can be configured like a router can be, and it would also avoid degradation of smartphone's battery life because of regular use of hotspot.

Comment: Thanks, but routers of any kind are really expensive here, and I have an old mobile for sharing internet. I know and understand that it's not the best option but it could be a solution until I can get a real real router.